# Amazon Linux curl

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services

bash -c "$(curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh)"

I run the above script on and ec2 instance running Amazon linux to install prediction IO. Nothing happens no error.  Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That command downloads a file in silent mode `$(curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh)` and then run the file with `bash -c`.
you should run the command in separated steps to check what it is going on

```
curl -O  https://install.prediction.io/install.sh
chmod +x install.sh 
./install.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

First, check whether the like https://install.prediction.io/install.sh is accessible from your Amazon EC2.

```
 curl -v https://install.prediction.io/install.sh
```

If its working, try this

```
 curl -s https://install.prediction.io/install.sh | bash
```